# Rails date_select and tabIndex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tabindex

Attempting to set the tabIndex for date_select has proven to be difficult out of the box.

```
<%= f.date_select :card_expires_on, 
{:order => [:month, :year], :discard_day => true, :start_year => Date.today.year,
 :end_year => (Date.today.year+10), :add_month_numbers => true}, 
{:tabindex => "11"} %>
```

That is the best I've come up with, but that sets the tabIndex to be 11 for both of the select dropdowns. How do I set the tabIndex of the month to 11 and the tabIndex of the year to 12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't with the standard `date_select` helper, all of the html options get passed to the `DateTimeSelector` class, which creates drop downs for each field with these html options.

You could modify this class to do what you need (see date_helper.rb in action pack if rails3) or you could write your own date_select that does this etc.

Comment: As an aside what you're trying to do sounds like a minor UX annoyance: tabindex should generally be consistent across 1 form.

Comment: Exactly. I have 10 inputs ahead of it, then this would be inputs 11 and 12...Or did you mean something else?